# JAVA: Deleting a div generated by a for loop

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, mysql, jsp

How do you delete a div that is generated by a for loop? I have this code that generates divs:

EDIT: I have tried the changes of @Andrew Liberio but what happened is that my applicant divs have scattered all over the place. This is the new code and the script as well. Notice how I had put the ending semicolon of the for loop in order to get put the the index in the ajax. (Not seen in the code block for some reason but it goes like this >/script> <%}%>

```
                <% ApplicantDAO applicantDAO = new ApplicantDAO();%>
                <% for (int i = 0; i < applicantDAO.viewApplicant().size(); i++) {%>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">


                        <div class="list-group">


                            <a  class="list-group-item active">
                                <img src = "th_1x1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" alt = "Responsive Image" width = "100%" height ="100">
                                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" id="guardName<%=+i%>" id="guardName<%=+i%>"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantFirstName() + " "%>
                                    <%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantLastName()%></h4>                 
                            </a>
                            <a  class="list-group-item">
                                <p class="list-group-item-text" id="applyingFor<%=+i%>" id="applyingFor<%=+i%>"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplyingFor()%></p>
                            </a>
                             <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" href="#moreDetails<%=+i%>">
                                <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="moreDetails">More Details</button>                                   
                            </a>
                                <a  class="list-group-item">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                            </a>

            <script>
                                                        $(".delete").on("click", function () {
                                                            var id = $(this).attr("delete<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>"); //get the id of the row
                                                            $.post("url_to_servlet_responsible_to_exclude_item", {
                                                                tId: id,
                                                                someOtherData: "anyData"
                                                            }).done(function () {
                                                                //if everything went ok,
                                                                //delete the div
                                                                $("div#" + id).remove();
                                                            });
                                                        })


            </script>
```

But I dont know how to delete it at the same time delete it at the database. I use a jsp and servlet. This is my code for delete:

```
         public boolean rejectApplicant(Applicant RejectedApplicant) {
    try {
        DBConnectionFactory myFactory = DBConnectionFactory.getInstance();
        Connection conn = myFactory.getConnection();

        String query = "delete from applicant where applicantID = ?";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);


        int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
        pstmt.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ApplicantDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think that the same logic applies when transferring the values of the div to the database. The page is an applicant page where applicants are screened then if they do not pass, they will be removed and when they are accepted, the values will be passed to the database. Please suggest on what should I do. I already searched javascript and jquery but I just dont understand the terms like nodes etc. Any help or leads would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: pass the id to servlet and it will call method  , that method you can put it in a java class

Comment: Put an id on each of the your outer divs so you can identify them, then remove the div with the appropriate id at deletion time.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an id to each div or/and to each button as @LAROmega suggested.

```
<div class="column" id="<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantId()">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete" aria-label="Left Align" id="<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantId()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Then, you could use this script to delete the row using AJAX.

```
$(".delete").on("click", function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id"); //get the id of the row
$.post("url_to_servlet_responsible_to_exclude_item", {
   tId: id,
   someOthetData: "anyData"
}).done(function(){
   //if everything went ok,
   //delete the div
   $("div#" + id).remove();
});
})
```

Comment: Can you please check the new code now? I think I am implementing this wrong

Comment: Yes, it's little bit mixed up. The JavaScript code doesn't have to stay inside the For Loop. It's gonna be outside of it. This JavaScript code just have to be executed once.

Comment: But if I do this, I can't assign the id based on the id from the for loop. Or I am understanding this wrong? thanks!

Comment: You will assign the id to your div using the loop, that is correct. But I want to you notice that the JS function will listen to all button clicks, since you put the class 'delete' on each generated div and the JS function is: `$(".delete").on("click", ...)`.
That's why you must remove the JS script to outside the For Loop.

Comment: Thank you for making me notice it. However, nothing is still happening after I change it. is this because of the id? or the $("div#" + id).remove(). I am new to AJAX and JS/Jquery so I dont quite understand most of the code. Thanks once again for helping me learn and answering my questions

Comment: @bryxwarrior, I've mentioned AJAX because I think it's nice, once the browser won't update the entire page, just the div. However, if you don't feel confortable using AJAX yet, you can always do it in a classic way. For instance, you can create your button inside a `<form>` tag. Each submit will force browser to update the page. Doing this, it will just generate the divs minus the last one which was deleted. You can eliminate most of JavaScript with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should not use the function `on("click"` in a loop.
You should use class `delete` for each button that you want to delete.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete" data-id="<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>" aria-label="Left Align">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Outside of the loop, you call function `on click`

```
$(".delete").on("click", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); //get the id of the row
        $.post("url_to_servlet_responsible_to_exclude_item", {
            tId: id,
            someOtherData: "anyData"
        }).done(function () {
            //if everything went ok,
            //delete the div
            $("div#" + id).remove();
        });
    })
```